# Specifying cardinalities of entities

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using a Xampp server to manage database of my website. I use foreign key constraints to draw relationship among entities or tables. How can i specify cardinalities among them e.g. one-one, one-many?

Comment: Do you want the child column to be unique ? In that case you can put a `unique` key on it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! Please add more details to your question. As a far as I know, cardinalities are a result of your db schema (how your entities are implemented as tables and columns). So please give us some details about your table definitions, or at least an example.

Comment: I have two tables named 'consultancy'  and 'patient_retention'. consultancy table stores record of patient consultancies. Primary key of this table goes into 'patient_retention' table which stores record of patient temporary retention. There can be only one patient retention against one consultancy. How can I add this specification or cardinality of one-one in my tables relation?